# Usercontrol derived from abstract class

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

i am building a dynamic Winforms UI based on 12 Usercontrols which are selectable by a combobox and are derived from an abstract class (to provide a unified api).

Initiating all of them takes about 800ms (much too slow and useless because only one will be used after selection). But i have to init them to access a public Property 'Description' which i display in the combobox.

I would like to access the Property(field, const) static. But thats not possible with an interface or abstract class.

I could store the relation (UserControl <-> Description) in a Dictionay<type, string>.
But the 'Description' belongs to the object.

Is there any way override/inherit a public static function/poperty/field/attribute which can be accessed static via an interface/abstract class/Reflection. So i access the Description of the Usercontrol via interface/abstract/Reflection class without instantiating the derived class?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what `System.Attribute` is designed for, specifically in your case you can use `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Attribute is designed to do exactly this.

For example:

```
[System.ComponentModel.Description("This is my fantastic control!")]
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    //...
}
```

Then when you want to get the value:

```
public string GetDescription(Type t)
{
    System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute attrib = t.GetCustomAttribute<System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute>();

    if (attrib != null)
        return attrib.Description;

    return string.Empty;
}
```

And to call it:

`string myDescription = GetDescription(typeof(MyControl));`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. Is there any chance of a compile-time-check, that the derived classes have the attribute set? On the other hand, writing a unit-test with reflection would be simple...

Comment: No, nothing compile time for attributes since they aren't required to be implemented on derived classes (but you can set one on the base class that may get inherited by default depending on the attribute).